# Error instantiating application scoped instance of type 'className' for destination 'destinationName'

Tags: java, apache-flex

I got a StackOverflow error, so i thought asking in stackoverflow.

```
Send failed
Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Status 500: url: 'http://localhost:8080/context/messagebroker/amf'
```

And this will come up when u type the messagebroker servlet url:

```
HTTP 500 - 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error instantiating application scoped instance of type ''className' for destination destinationName.
    flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet.init(MessageBrokerServlet.java:188)
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

flex.messaging.config.ConfigurationException: Error instantiating application scoped instance of type 'classNamefor destination 'destinationName'.
    flex.messaging.factories.JavaFactory.createFactoryInstance(JavaFactory.java:143)
    flex.messaging.FactoryDestination.createFactoryInstance(FactoryDestination.java:256)
    flex.messaging.FactoryDestination.getFactoryInstance(FactoryDestination.java:239)
    flex.messaging.FactoryDestination.getFactoryInstance(FactoryDestination.java:227)
    flex.messaging.services.remoting.adapters.JavaAdapter.validateInstanceSettings(JavaAdapter.java:556)
    flex.messaging.services.remoting.adapters.JavaAdapter.start(JavaAdapter.java:355)
    flex.messaging.Destination.start(Destination.java:281)
    flex.messaging.services.AbstractService.startDestinations(AbstractService.java:735)
    flex.messaging.services.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:176)
    flex.messaging.MessageBroker.startServices(MessageBroker.java:2217)
    flex.messaging.MessageBroker.start(MessageBroker.java:352)
    flex.messaging.AsyncMessageBroker.start(AsyncMessageBroker.java:608)
    flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet.init(MessageBrokerServlet.java:153)
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
    className.<init>(className.java:12)
```

Comment: You should post the answer down below, since that is where people tend to look for them.

Comment: Ok, (random chars to reach 15).

Comment: Like the first sentence of your query @user1601662!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But by the time i was typing this question, i found out what it was... I had a circular reference on a global object declared on a application scoped class. It was an unintended copy-paste... So when the `messagebroker/amf` was launching, it got stuck on the circular reference instancing the same object over and over. I'm leaving the post in case someone else comes into this error, because google didn't help much.